# all-in-one gis packages for windows 8.1?

Tags: open-source-gis, windows-8, free-software, installation

Is there an all-in-one installer that allows having all open-source gis apps installed in windows 8.1? with all apps I mean for instance postgresql, postgis, mapserver, qgis, grass.

I have cygwin installed, but I've read that it's way better to install these apps in windows. In case I need to query my psql db located in my postgresql windows installation from cygwin (ie. shell terminal), could that be possible?

Comment: Does the OSGEO package not install correctly on Windows 8?

Comment: OpenGeo Suite http://boundlessgeo.com/solutions/opengeo-suite/

Comment: OpenGeo Suite looks nice but no money at all to have it. OSGEO seems to be what I need, I will take a closer look at it, thanks.

Comment: How about the [OSGeo-Live](http://live.osgeo.org/en/index.html) Virtual Machine? _"OSGeo-Live is a self-contained Virtual Machine based on Xubuntu, that allows you to try a wide variety of open source geospatial software without installing anything. It is composed entirely of free software, allowing it to be freely distributed, duplicated and passed around. It provides pre-configured applications for a range of geospatial use cases, including storage, publishing, viewing, analysis and manipulation of data. It also contains sample datasets and documentation."_

Comment: I tried before Xubuntu in a VM, but it was slow, probably because I had only 2GB RAM which seems to be not enough according to some readings. That's why I opted to install everything directly in windows, but I need to deal with apps that run only in unix/linux environments such as seismic unix, and they are related to gmt through simple bash scripts, moreover I need to query my pgsql db to map things, but don't want to boot to linux as I used to do. I think the solution is simply to stick with win8 and call things from cygwin, but I need to query my db from it, would that be possible?

Comment: To keep your question standalone I would recommend revising it to account for any clarifications requested via comments.  Before it has an answer is the ideal time for this.

Comment: I am not sure about the current OpenGeo Suite version but there used to be also a free community version available. Naturally that came without support services.